# Check if properties of button are identical - python

Tags: python, fltk

I am making a fltk python program and want to simpify:

```
for i in range(9):
   if b[i].label()==b[i+3].label()==b[i+6].label():
       ...
```

How can I check that all of them are the same by comparing them in a list like

```
l=[i,i+3,i+6]
```

and having it do the same thing as the above code as simple as possible.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `reduce` and `bool`

```
In [9]: myList = [1,1,1,1,1]

In [11]: bool(reduce(lambda x,y: x if x == y else False, myList))
Out[11]: True
In [14]: myList = [1,1,1,1,1,2]

In [15]: reduce(lambda x,y: x if x == y else False, myList)
Out[15]: False
```

Or `set`

```
In [22]: myList = [1,1,1,1,1,2]

In [23]: len(set(myList)) == 1
Out[23]: False
```